# Which wire size and conduit for a 200A subpanel?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, conduit

I recently got a service upgrade to 200A.

My old sub panel (from which all branch circuits connect) was 100A and recently got upgraded as well but the feeders are unchanged. To support this, the main breaker from the sub panel (200A which came with the panel) was removed.
The feeder is currently protected by 100A in the Main Service Panel (MSP).

If I wanted to put the 200A breaker back in, which wire would I need? Do I really need AWG 0/3?

Is it correct that I would need at least a 1-1/2 EMT conduit?

Of course, after replacing the feeders I would like to replace the breaker in the MSP from 100A to 200A as well.

Comment: Is this conduit being run inside a wall, on the surface of a wall, or...?

Comment: Is there a breaker in the main panel for the sub panel?  If so what size is it?  Sub panel main breakers become mainly local disconnect in use, it does not protect the feeder wires.  That is done by the breaker in the main panel.

Comment: You need to know the size of the breaker for the sub panel, and the size/gauge of the feeder wires.  Then check on a feed wire size chart, which will be different than the regular gauge sizes for normal circuits.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel first ~3ft exterior wall, a few inches through exterior wall and remaining part (15ft?) through crawl space.

Comment: @crip659 there is a 100A in the MSP panel right now. Having a “local disconnect” in the sub panel would be one of the goals but I only have the 200A that came with the sub panel. Would it be legal to use the 200A main breaker as local disconnect switch, assuming the feeder is protected by 100A in the MSP?

Comment: @crip659 of course, if I were to replace the feeder I would replace the breaker for the feeder in the MSP from currently 100A to 200A. But for this I’d want to know what the required gauge and conduit size is. I want to get an idea how challenging/expensive it is (I know it will be at least a few hundred for the copper alone)

Comment: This link gives feeder sizes, for 200amps you 2/0 Cu or 3/0Al.  This link for conduit seems to say 1 1/2, https://www.elliottelectric.com/StaticPages/ElectricalReferences/ElectricalTables/Conduit_Fill_Table.aspx   https://learnmetrics.com/electrical-feeder-size-chart/ .  The breaker in the sub panel can be 200 amps even if the breaker in the main is only 40 amps.

Comment: @crip659 The NEC 310.12 table in the feeder size chart is for "conductors supplying the entire load associated with a one-family dwelling." That means the service from the utility to the main disconnect, or the feeder from the main disconnect to the main breaker panel. A feeder going to a subpanel, though, doesn't get the 83% discount -- a 200 A feeder to a subpanel, ie a panel not serving the entire load associated with a dwelling, would require 250 kcmil aluminum rather than 4/0.

Comment: @GregHill This is counterintuitive, can you explain? Why do I need a smaller size when the conductors need to "supply the entire load" but no discount when not supplying the entire load (i.e., subpanel)? Makes no sense to me. Wire from utility should be thicker than a wire to a subpanel. Followup question: In my case the MSP only feeds one subpanel (which is more or less my "main panel"). So it still "supplies the entire load with the one-family dwelling" but it's just a sub-panel. Is it 4/0 Al or 250kcmil Al?

Comment: @divB I agree 100% that it's counterintuitive. I don't know, but I would guess that it has to do with the load calculation procedure causing people to "round up" to say a 200 A panel, so in effect the code allows a "round down" on the wire that feeds the entire house. Maybe branches and feeders inside the house don't have the same tendency to over-size and so aren't allowed the 83% ampacity de-rate bonus.

Comment: If a main panel feeds nothing else except the subpanel then yes the feeder to the sub supplies the entire load and 4/0 Al would meet code. Confession: I learned about all this when upgrading my own main panel. Mine was as described here and I replaced the main panel with one having room for a feeder breaker for a detached garage. At that point the 4/0 Al from main to sub inside the house no longer "served the entire load" and should have been upgraded. Thankfully the inspector let it slide. For new work, like upgrading a 100 A feeder to 200 A, I think he'd have required it be 250 kcmil Al.

Comment: @GregHill thanks! Do you want to. Copy this into an answer so I can accept? This Sounds like the answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sizing a subpanel feeder for a one- or two-family dwelling under NEC rules, after all the load calculations are done, there's another question that must be answered. It is this: does that subpanel serve *the entire load associated with the dwelling?* In other words, are there (or could there be) circuits added *in the main panel* so that some of the load is served at the main panel and other of the load is served at this subpanel?

When *the entire load associated with the dwelling* is carried through a given feeder (or a service), NEC allows a little break in the wire sizing. The wire may be sized for 83% of the overcurrent protection limit. For example, if the overcurrent protection is at 200 A the wire may be sized for 166 A.

Feeders and services often use THWN or XHHW insulated wire and are sized for 75° C. When using aluminum conductors the 4/0 gauge with 180 A ampacity fits the bill for 166 A sizing. When the 83% de-rate does not apply, though, aluminum 250 kcmil would have to be used to meet the full 200 A ampacity.

A short feeder, or one where conduit size is expensive, might opt for copper conductors instead of aluminum. The same de-rate rules apply.

This does seem counter-intuitive. I don't know but I could speculate that the NEC load calculation procedure causes a whole-home load to be a little over-stated, so they give a little back in the service/feeder sizing. Such excess may not be incorporated in the general case, though, so no de-rate is offered generally.